# git: 'credential-wincred' is not a git command. See 'git --help'. on mac

Tags: git, gitlab

How to solve this error on "MacBook pro".

> git: 'credential-wincred' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
>
> git: 'credential-wincred' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
>
> remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied
>   fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://gitlab01.xxxxx.com.tw/xxxxx/xxxxxxx.git/'

I use "git config --system --unset credential.helper" & "git config --global credential.helper wincred
", and nothing work for me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to use the `wincred` credential helper, which is only available on Windows, on macOS. You mentioned that you've run `git config --global credential.helper wincred`, which sets the credential helper to `wincred`. When Git tries to invoke it, it fails because it's unavailable.

Instead, you should run `git config --unset-all credential.helper` and run `git config --global credential.helper osxkeychain`. That will result in you using the macOS Keychain for storing credentials, which will work on macOS.

Comment: Helped for me on Mac machine

Comment: Doesn't work if you have multiple credential helpers

Comment: Yes, in that case, you need to edit the configuration by hand and remove `wincred`.  There really isn't a way around that.

Comment: This is only for Mac, not for Linux

Comment: Yes, on Linux, you'd use `libsecret` instead of `osxkeychain`, but on Debian and Ubuntu at least, you have to compile it yourself first.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem on Windows using WSL and ubuntu, I had to do `git config --global --unset-all credential.helper` to remove the value, without the --global tag the --unset-all did nothing.